# Css scoped in single Component

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have index.css,style.css and index.js, header.js in my react code both CSS is applying to a single component how to block applying CSS

Comment: can you elaborate and make things more clear.

Comment: Try to add a class to parent element and then using that parent try to apply CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, and you want to make sure that the both css's are not applying too the whole app, you should be more specific about your css rules. try to nest them, or use sass.